# How to scan multiple .txt files for a string with a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, match

So I have a string that I'd like to use a regular expression.

```
regex = "hello( |/n)(/w*)"
```

I have several files that I'd like to comb through to see if they contain strings that can match my query. This would be something like:

hi **hello world**
hello .nope **hello

you** yes no maybe

I also just want to return just the matched strings, so in the example above, "hello world" and "hello you".

I'm having difficulty returning just the matched string and not the whole line, as well as with getting the regex to work as a variable, like so:

```
/#{regex}/.match(textfile.txt)
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Try to well format your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Off-question: I'd use `rgrep` (`grep -r`) on linux. If your script is mainly about "eating" files, consider using rubys `ARGF` (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-argf).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
regex = 'hello( |\n)(\w*)'
matches = /#{regex}/.match(textfile.txt).captures
```

First off, you need to use backslashes to escape special symbols such as `\n`. You can use single quotes since it will take the string literally, but if you use double quotes it will evaluate the escape sequences, so you'd need to escape them twice like this: `regex = "hello( |\\n)(\\w*)"`

`.captures` will return an array of the captured groups. If you want only the word captured after the space/newline, you can using the `[]` operator like this:

```
word = /#{regex}/.match(textfile.txt)[2]
```

`[0]` will return the entire match, `[1]` returns the first captured group, which is the space/newline, and `[2]` is the second captured group, containing the word following "hello".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scan` method to capture all the possible matches to your regex.

`scan` method will grab all the groups you want to capture and put them in a array, but first, let's fix your regex.

```
regex = "hello( |/n)(/w*)"
```

1. you will want to use `\`, not `/`, you use `/` around the entire expression to tell ruby it is an regular expression.
2. You want to use `/` around the expression, and not `"`, it will make it easier to use later, otherwise you need to convert it to regex.
3. Using `()` means creating a capture group, so you can refer to it with `$1` as the first group, `$2` as the second group. This is what `scan` will return, so you don't need them in this case.
4. Based on your question, you need to capture a word after `hello`, so you don't want to use `*`, which means capture 0 or more word characters, you want to use `+`, which captures 1 or more characters.

So you regex should look like

```
regex = /hello[\s\n]\w+/
```

If you run `scan` with this regex and your original string

```
str = 'hi hello world hello .nope hello
you yes no maybe'

regex = /hello[\s\n]\w+/

str.scan(regex)
```

This returns

```
["hello world", "hello\nyou"]
```